# ng-click not working with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ng-if

**Why does the second button not work, when ng-if is used?**

I want to realize a button that is present only when the model value is set / not ""/ not null.

Template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="blub"/>
<br/>
<button ng-click="blub = 'xxxx'">X</button>
<br/>
<button ng-click="blub = 'yyyy'" ng-if="blub.length">Y</button>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('Main', function ($scope) {
    // nothing to do here
});
```

To play around: <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufcpvdL7/1/)</kbd>

Comment: What do you use `ng-if` for?

Comment: It checks the scope variable `blub` for a length != 0. Then it shows me a button. In the end I want to use that button to unset the variable. This allows the user to remove the value completely. E.g. `blub` is a part of an object and should only be set if the user wants it to set.

Comment: BTW: I also ran into this [bug](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ng-click-wrapped-by-label-doesnt-work-when-migrated-from-beta-8-to-beta-11/8000/3) (Ionic?) which made the ng-click useless if a <label> is wrapped around-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: ng-if not working in combination with ng-click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812116/angularjs-ng-if-not-working-in-combination-with-ng-click)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) Instead of `ng-if`. That should work.

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarxukb4/)</kbd>

Comment: How did you make the Fiddle button?

Comment: Wrap the link between `<kbd></kbd>` tag :).

Comment: Cool, I was about to give answer that use ng-show but was unable to make make fiddle of angular code :(

Comment: @MuhammadReda It's beautiful, but really [not semantic at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd). Please stop doing that.

Comment: I think it should be comment, not a answer

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't work because ng-if is creating a new scope and interpreting your blub = 'yyyy' as defining a new local variable in the new scope.
You can test this by putting the second button to:

```
<button ng-click="$parent.blub = 'yyyy'" ng-if="blub.length">Y</button>
```

However $parent is an ugly feature.

Comment: It's very easy to bloat your code with $parent, for example chaining $parent calls ($parent.$parent.property).

Answer (score 5):

The button doesn't work because of the nested scope created by `ng-if`. The `blub` bound to the second button is not the same `blub` that's bound to the first one.

You can use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`, since it uses its parent's scope, but that's just avoiding the problem instead of solving it. Read about [nested scopes](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html) so you can understand what actually happened.

Also, check this out: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s29s8r06/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Try putting a *magic* dot on the variable

```
<input type="text" ng-model="bl.ub"/>
<br/>
<button ng-click="bl.ub = 'xxxx'">X</button>
<br/>
<button ng-click="bl.ub = 'yyyy'" ng-if="bl.ub.length">Y</button>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufcpvdL7/1/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use : `[hidden]="!expression"`