# How to change text element into input field on click using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering how this can be done in AngularJS.

Having this list of keywords and an edit button next to it.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="keyword in keywords">
        <td>
            <strong id="keyword.name">{{ keyword.name }}</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="editKeyword(keyword.name)">Edit</button>
            <button ng-click="deleteKeyword(keyword.name)">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Now in my controller I have something like this.

```
$scope.editKeyword = function(name){
    console.log(name);
    //something done to change the <strong> element into a text input
};
```

How can I replace the "strong" element with a text input field via the controller. Can this be done in angularJS?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest way would be do it directly in the template using `ng-if`

```
<td>
     <strong id="keyword.name" ng-if="!editMode">{{ keyword.name }}</strong>
     <span ng-if="editMode">
        <input ng-model="keyword.name">
        <button ng-click="save(keyword); editMode = false">Save</button>
     <span>
</td>
<td>
    <button ng-click="editKeyword(keyword); editMode = true">Edit</button>
    <button ng-click="deleteKeyword(keyword)">Delete</button>
</td>
```

Comment: That's a good work around. I thought Angular has a way to somehow automate that. But this works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: There are modules that have far more features/style etc but I only showed you the simplest approach

Comment: Yes this will suffice. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9):

As charlie mentionned, `ng-if` would do the job. 
There is also 'ng-switch', which was made exactly for this type of situation.

```
<tr ng-repeat="keyword in keywords">
    <td ng-switch="mode[$index]">
        <input ng-switch-when="edit" id="edit" ng-model="keyword.name">
        <strong ng-switch-default id="keyword.name">{{ keyword.name }}</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button ng-click="editKeyword(keyword.name, $index)">Edit</button>
        <button ng-click="deleteKeyword(keyword.name)">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the controller would look like:

```
$scope.editKeyword = function(name, index){
    $scope.mode[index] = "edit";
    console.log(name);
    //something done to change the <strong> element into a text input
};
```

And you change $scope.mode[index] to anything else when you're done editing.

Comment: As a note, you could add `ng-blur="mode[$index]='view'"` to the input element.  This is a more minimalist option to return to the initial 'view' state, instead of the 'save' button in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

charlietfl's suggestion:

> Blockquote Simplest way would be do it directly in the template using `ng-if`

`ng-if` doesn't work `ng-show` does.

Source: [ng-click not working with ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27039689)